# UINavigationBar without NavigationController ios7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, ios7-statusbar

I have a UIViewController with a UINavigationBar at the top.
The viewController gets on the screen via a Modal transition.
On iOS7 the problem is that the navigationBar doesn't get stretched, and as a result has a static height of 44px. This causes the statusBar to overlap it.

How can I make the navigationBar resize its height on iOS7?